# If $u$ and $v$ have weak derivatives,what about $uv$?

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, distribution-theory

$\Omega$ is a domain in $R^n$, Let $u\in L^1_{\text{loc}}(\Omega)$. If there exists $g_i \in  L^1_{\text{loc}}(\Omega)$ such that 
$$\int_\Omega g_i \phi \, dx=-\int_\Omega u \frac{\partial \phi_i}{\partial x},\phi \in C_0^\infty(\Omega)$$
Then we say $u$ has weak partial derivatives $g_i$.

If $u$ and $v$ have weak partial derivatives, does $uv$ have 
weak partial derivatives? Or what conditions should we add to $u$ and $v$?

Comment: The first thing to note is that $uv$ does not need to belong to $L^1_{loc}(\Omega)$, however, if you add the hypothesis that $u$ or $v$ beong to $L^\infty_{loc}(\Omega)$, then you can get your result.

Comment: In my first comment, we have to change "or" by "and": $u$ and $v$.

Answer (score 1):

If $\def\loc{\text{loc}}u,v\in L^\infty_{\loc}(\Omega)$, then $uv\in L^1_{\loc}(\Omega)$ and $u\frac{\partial v}{\partial x_i}+v\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_i}\in L^1_{\loc}(\Omega)$. It remains to show that if $U\subset \Omega$ is a open set with $\overline{U}\subset\Omega$ compact, then $$\int_U (uv)\frac{\partial\varphi}{\partial x_i}=-\int_U \left(u\frac{\partial v}{\partial x_i}+v\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_i}\right)\varphi,\ \forall\ \varphi\in C_0^\infty(U)$$

To this end I refer your to [Brezis](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&frm=1&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CDIQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.math.uni.wroc.pl%2F~karch%2Fanaliza_nieliniowa%2Fref%2FBREZIS__Functional_Analysis__Sobolev_Spaces_and_Partial_Differential_Equations__Universitext_.pdf&ei=uHBNUty3BILo8wSHvYH4Cw&usg=AFQjCNGP9nqQmNf4F1EOrBbb_glm25twWQ&sig2=t8C5dKm1YMPQF4BTmweNPw&bvm=bv.53537100,d.eWU) page 269, Proposition 9.4.

Answer (score 0):

You can also ask that $uv$, $u'v$ and $uv'$ are in $L^1_{loc}$ : then the usual product rule holds. (Use the sequential characterization of weak derivatives with $\mathcal C^\infty$ functions and pass to the $L^1_{loc}$ limit in the usual product rule).